# Icon size in preference screen for Amazon Kindle Fire HD?

Tags: android, icons, preferenceactivity, kindle-fire

I've got Android application running on Amazon Kindle Fire HD 8.9". It's got a full HD display with carousel home screen where icons are 675x675 px big. 
First problem I had was using standard small app icons which are stretched and blurry on this device. I solved it by adding new folder

```
drawable-large-mdpi
```

into /res folder and adding 675x675 icon in here.
This works and app icon in carousel is nice, big and sharp.

Second problem is that this big icon appears also in the SettingsActivity which is based on PreferenceActivity (PreferenceScreen and PreferenceCategory used in layout xml).
So, my question is how to use different (small one) icon here?
I tried

```
android:icon
```

but that doesn't work. Anybody knows?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sideloading/testing your .apk then it will only use the default small icon. If you deliver the app through the appstore then it will use the assets you specify in the developer portal for the launcher carousel

https://developer.amazon.com/post/Tx18I929G17TAAS/Submitting-Visual-Marketing-Assets-Marketing-Tip-of-the-Day-4.html

Comment: I am not going to deliver app through appstore.
I am not sure if I understand your answer. I've managed to show big icon in carousel home screen which is good, but this big one is also showed in SettingsActivity which is based on PreferenceActivity and that looks terrible. So my goal is to find out if it is possible to use different icon there. Small one, obviously.